# Pojo class creation from Sqlite cursor is taking too much time

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview, database-performance

My query is taking < 3 milli sec to execute. But the problem is, I am creating a pojo class objects from the cursor I got from query execution. This object creation and setting values to fields is taking too much time more than 140 milli sec. Pojo class has around 36 fields. Any suggestion to solve this problem.?

Thanks

Comment: i think you can use postDelayed handler to vary the time of execution

Comment: You can use _CursorLoader_  for that.

Comment: I have tried the solutions you have suggested. But I am still seeing same same message in the log(i.e app is doing too much work in main thread).
After I got the result I am updating the adapter. I mean I am adding all the items to Arraylist which is used within the adapter and I am calling notifydataSetChanged() method within runOnUiThread. If I not call this method I dont see any message in log.
I have also tried notifyItemInserted() but same result. notifyDatasetChanged method should be called in the main thread right?

Answer (score 1):

I know that the `c.getColumnIndex()` method takes more time. The best method that I know to speed up the things is the following:

```
Cursor c = null;
try {
    c = db.query(......);
    if(c != null) {

        int channelIdIndex = c.getColumnIndex(OptimizedMessage.CHANNEL_ID);
        int clientIdIndex = c.getColumnIndex(OptimizedMessage.CLIENT_ID);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            OptimizedMessage newMessage = new OptimizedMessage();
            newMessage.setChannelId(c.getLong(channelIdIndex));
            newMessage.setClientId(c.getLong(clientIdIndex));

            messages.add(newMessage);
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
}
```

You can see that the `c.getColumnIndex()` method is used only once.

Comment: I have tried the solutions you have suggested. But I am still seeing same same message in the log(i.e app is doing too much work in main thread).
After I got the result I am updating the adapter. I mean I am adding all the items to Arraylist which is used within the adapter and I am calling notifydataSetChanged() method within runOnUiThread. If I not call this method I dont see any message in log.
I have also tried notifyItemInserted() but same result. notifyDatasetChanged method should be called in the main thread right?

Comment: Yes but then I think your problem is not with the POJO creation. It is something else. Please try to use custom loaders where you can build everything in the background thread and use the ViewHolder pattern on your adapter side. That is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

How many objects are you instantiating? 
36 fields doesn't seen too much.

If you have many objects, you could instantiate them in a separate thread. Of course you will have to set up some kind of callback to find out when everything is loaded